# Как сделать гиперссылку в QLabel?

Tags: python, pyqt5

Не знаю как вообще создаются гиперссылки. Попробывал, чет не пошло. Можно ли сделать, чтобы при нажатии на нее открывался браузер, открывающий сайт по этой ссылки?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При помощи [`setOpenExternalLinks(bool)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlabel.html#openExternalLinks-prop) можно открывать ссылки в `QLabel`

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QLabel, QApplication, QVBoxLayout
import sys


class Main(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        label = QLabel('<a href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/851355/255866">Переход на вопрос</a>')
        label.setOpenExternalLinks(True)
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(label)
        self.setLayout(layout)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Main()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```